# Recursively creating a list of descendants in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, append

I'm really new to Prolog and am struggling with recursively appending to lists. I'm trying to create a program that tells you if one person is a descendant of the other, and the list of descendants between them. For example, sample data and desired output:

```
parent(greatgrandma, grandma).
parent(grandma, mom).
parent(mom, daughter).

?- relatives(greatgrandma, daughter, Lineage).
Lineage = [greatgrandma, grandma, mom, daughter]

?- relatives(mom, son, Lineage).
False.
```

I'm able to search recursively to check whether or not two persons are related with the following code, and have it working as a test base case ...

```
relatives(X, Y, Lineage):- isChild(X,Y, Lineage).
isChild(X,Y, Lineage):- parent(X,Y), append([X], [Y], Lineage).
isChild(X,Y, Lineage):- parent(X,Z), isChild(Z,Y, Lineage).
```

But everything I've tried so far to build a list from this descendant search has not worked. Here is the closest I've gotten:

```
relatives(X, Y, Lineage):- append([X], Lineage, NewLineage), isChild(X,Y, NewLineage).
isChild(X,Y, Lineage):- parent(X,Z), append(Lineage, [Z], NewLineage), isChild(Z,Y, NewLineage).
isChild(X,Y, Lineage):- parent(X,Y), append(Lineage, [Y], NewLineage).
```

```
[trace]  ?- relatives(grandma, daughter, P).
   Call: (10) relatives(grandma, daughter, _12442) ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:append([grandma], _12442, _12904) ? creep
   Exit: (11) lists:append([grandma], _12442, [grandma|_12442]) ? creep
   Call: (11) isChild(grandma, daughter, [grandma|_12442]) ? creep
   Call: (12) parent(grandma, _13040) ? creep
   Exit: (12) parent(grandma, mom) ? creep
   Call: (12) lists:append([grandma|_12442], [mom], _13136) ? creep
   Exit: (12) lists:append([grandma], [mom], [grandma, mom]) ? creep
   Call: (12) isChild(mom, daughter, [grandma, mom]) ? creep
   Call: (13) parent(mom, _13272) ? creep
   Exit: (13) parent(mom, daughter) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:append([grandma, mom], [daughter], _13368) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:append([grandma, mom], [daughter], [grandma, mom, daughter]) ? creep
   Call: (13) isChild(daughter, daughter, [grandma, mom, daughter]) ? creep
   Call: (14) parent(daughter, _13510) ? creep
   Fail: (14) parent(daughter, _13554) ? creep
   Redo: (13) isChild(daughter, daughter, [grandma, mom, daughter]) ? creep
   Call: (14) parent(daughter, daughter) ? creep
   Fail: (14) parent(daughter, daughter) ? creep
   Fail: (13) isChild(daughter, daughter, [grandma, mom, daughter]) ? creep
   Redo: (12) isChild(mom, daughter, [grandma, mom]) ? creep
   Call: (13) parent(mom, daughter) ? creep
   Exit: (13) parent(mom, daughter) ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:append([grandma, mom], [daughter], _13914) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:append([grandma, mom], [daughter], [grandma, mom, daughter]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) isChild(mom, daughter, [grandma, mom]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) isChild(grandma, daughter, [grandma]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) relatives(grandma, daughter, []) ? creep
P = [] .
```

So I'm getting the list in the correct order of [grandma, mom, daughter], but I can't figure out how to have that be returned for the value of P instead of the empty list. Also, the test of using 'son' results in an endless recursive loop using this code, but not with the previous base case.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! If you want to go with this approach, the main thing missing is the following observation: If `isChild` both takes in a "current lineage" and is expected to produce a "new lineage", then it needs *two* lineage arguments. One for the "old" state, one for the "new" one.

Like this:

```
isChild(X,Y, Lineage, NewLineage) :-
    parent(X,Z),
    append(Lineage, [Z], Lineage2),
    isChild(Z,Y, Lineage2, NewLineage).
isChild(X,Y, Lineage, NewLineage) :-
    parent(X,Y),
    append(Lineage, [Y], NewLineage).
```

When you call this, you need to pass in a correct initial lineage to start with:

```
relatives(X, Y, Lineage) :-
    isChild(X,Y, [X], Lineage).
```

And this now behaves like you want:

```
?- relatives(grandma, daughter, Lineage).
Lineage = [grandma, mom, daughter] ;
false.

?- relatives(mom, son, Lineage).
false.
```

**However,** the *real* answer is that you don't usually append things to lists when doing this sort of search in Prolog. Rather, you *pre*pend data. This is much more efficient, and also shorter and more readable, with fewer intermediate states:

```
ancestor_successor_lineage(Ancestor, Successor, [Ancestor, Successor]) :-
    parent(Ancestor, Successor).
ancestor_successor_lineage(Ancestor, Successor, [Ancestor | Lineage]) :-
    parent(Ancestor, Intermediate),
    ancestor_successor_lineage(Intermediate, Successor, Lineage).
```

Note that this is essentially the same as you would write if you were not interested in the lineage. Adding the recording of the intermediate states is simply adding one (not two, as before!) extra argument and a use of the list constructor `[_ | _]` to combine the "single step" of `parent` with the list from the recursive step. This is really the preferred way of writing this in Prolog.

This behaves the same as the other solution:

```
?- ancestor_successor_lineage(grandma, daughter, Lineage).
Lineage = [grandma, mom, daughter] ;
false.

?- ancestor_successor_lineage(mom, son, Lineage).
false.
```